# Select a div generated by CMS system

Tags: html, css, content-management-system

I've got a div with this on it: `data-plate-inline-text-editable="Element||940011||body"`

Now the number in the middle like `940011` is a number that changes but i need to select this div by something like this: `[data-plate-inline-text-editable="Element|| . ||body"]` in my `css.css`

Is there a way to do this?

ps. i can't add `div's` around or add some extra `class` or `id`. just this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could chain two attribute selectors:

```
[data-plate-inline-text-editable^="Element||"][data-plate-inline-text-editable$="||body"] {
   ...
}
```

to select all elements whose `data-plate-inline-text-editable` attribute start (`^=`) with `Element||` and end (`$=`) with `||body`